# Change modal UIImagePickerController parent view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to build an app that features a button on the first view, when you tap the button it presents the `UIImagePickerController` modal view. What I would ideally like is once you have taken you photo, when the modal view is dismissed, the original view which presented the image picker changes.

For example, the process would be VIEW 1 -- (tap button) --> MODAL IMAGE PICKER -- (close modal view) --> VIEW 2.

So far I've got the app loading the `UIImagePickerController` and once you are complete, within the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate method, it sets a `BOOL` value to `YES` and then within the `ViewDidAppear` of my original view (VIEW 1) it then presents a new modal with the next view.

The problem with this is that there is a delay between the closing the modal view and the next view (VIEW 2) appearing.

Does anyone know if the above is possible? If not, I might have to resort to displaying a spinner and saying "Processing image" between the image picker closing and the second view appearing.

Comment: How are you pushing to the next view?

Comment: Incorrect wording really. It opens a new modal view (updated the post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a navigation controller to solve this problem.

Create a navigation controller and push your first controller into it. Later from your first controller, present the picker modally. Pretty much the same until now except that we have added a navigation controller. This is what I did to get your desired result.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NewController *controller = [[NewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fantastic, works like a charm. The only thing I have done different is to not animate the push from controller 1 to 2, because the transition isn't visible, it shouldn't make any difference and not animating must save some resources I would have thought. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I changed it in my test code but didn't get around to updating it here.